# Is it a good idea to manage database with csv files?

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm working on a feature that imports users into a MySQL database.
The initial goal of this feature was to add new users from CSV files.

Gradually my client wants more of this tool. Indeed, if the CSV file contains a row with an already existed user, the data will be updated (the feature erases the old data with the new). So we implement it.

After that, he wants to update users (i.e. remove data, add data et cetera) but he already has a man/machine interface to do that.

I feel we're going in the wrong way.

What do you think about this ? Is it a good idea to manage database with csv files ?

Comment: In my opinion and experience, no, it's not a good idea. You end up with a (relational) database that is subject to the whims of a relationally-ignorant (usually "legacy") system managing part of it's data. A much better option is to put the database in charge of such data, and a new/updated application designed for it; and have the csv exported back out for use by older systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see no problem using CSV to do that. You need to define a clear file format which specify object type and action, like for example :

```
<object type>;<action>;<value1>;<value2>;etc…
```

So you can have

```
user;add;Bob;Stone;fr
```

then

```
user;update;Bob;Stone;uk
```

then

```
user;del;Bob;Stone
```

etc…

Comment: It seems to be a good idea. We'll see with our client to make a tool to manage the datas, using this way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.